# How to get value of field in array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

let's assume i have database structure as;

```
{
    name: "alex",
    age: 21,
    school: [
       {grade: 45, class: "elementary school", name: "blabla"},
       {grade: 89, class: "high school", name: "blabla2"},
       {grade: 12, class: "college", name: "blabla3"}
    ]
},
{
    name: "felix",
    age: 45,
    school: [
       {grade: 12, class: "elementary school", name: "bla"},
       {grade: 45, class: "high school", name: "bla2"},
       {grade: 16, class: "college", name: "bla3"}
    ]
}
```

what i want to do is get the school name for each name

```
{
    name: alex,
    school: ["blabla", "blabla2", "blabla3"]
},
{
    name: felix,
    school: ["bla", "bla2", "bla3"]
}
```

To be able achieve this,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {group: {_id: "$name", school: {$addToSet: {"$school.name"}}}}
])
```

But couldn't achieve. What should I modify?

Comment: You can use projection to get a value of field from array. Something like `db.collection.find({},{_id:0, name:1, "school.name": 1});` or use aggregate 
`db.collection.aggregate({$project:{_id:0, name:1, school:"$school.name"}});`. For distinct `name` value in each `school` document you can use `db.collection.aggregate({$project:{_id:0, name:1, school:{$setUnion:["$school.name", []]}}});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just unwinf the `school` array before grouping with a **`$unwind`** stage like this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$school"},
  {$group: {_id: "$name", school: {$addToSet: "$school.name"}}}
])
```

output:

```
{ "_id" : "felix", "school" : [ "bla3", "bla2", "bla" ] }
{ "_id" : "alex", "school" : [ "blabla3", "blabla2", "blabla" ] }
```